# Drawing of a cube file

Tags: plotting, chemistry

The following is a description of a typical cube file

[image]

Based on the above instructions, I wrote the following mathematica code：

```mathematica
(* === 1. File Name === *)

(* The name and location of the file to be read is specified here. *)

fileName = "https://dl-web.dropbox.com/s/aikd8iaxxvntifv/C3H4O2-Potential.cube";


(* === 2. Read All Lines === *)

(* Read all lines from the specified file. *)

lines = ReadList[fileName, String];



(* === 3. Comment Line === *)

(* Determine the line number for the comment line. *)

commentLine = 2;


(* === 4. Atom Count === *)

(* Determine the number of atoms and the line numbers where the atom coordinates are found. *)

atomNum = (lines[[3]] // StringSplit // ToExpression)[[1]];



(* === 5. Grid Size === *)

(* Determine the size of the grid and the line numbers where the grid dimensions are found. *)

gridLines = lines[[4 ;; 6]];
grid = ToExpression /@ StringSplit /@ gridLines;
gridSize = grid[[All, 1]];



(* === 6. Data Lines === *)

(* Determine the line numbers where the potential energy data starts and ends. *)

dataStart = 2 + 1 + 3 + atomNum + 1;
dataEnd = Length[lines];
dataLines = lines[[dataStart ;; dataEnd]];
data = Flatten[ToExpression /@ StringSplit /@ dataLines];


(* === 7. Potential Energy Data === *)

(* Reshape the potential energy data into a 3D array. *)

potentialData = ArrayReshape[data, gridSize];



(* === 8. Contour Plot === *)

(* Create a 3D contour plot of the potential energy data. *)

ListContourPlot3D@potentialData
```

[image]

The result was terrible, and then I used a different code：

```mathematica
minValue = Min[potentialData];
maxValue = Max[potentialData];

(*生成等值面级别列表*)
contourLevels = Range[minValue, maxValue, (maxValue - minValue)/20];

(*使用等值面级别列表绘制等值面图*)
ListContourPlot3D[potentialData, Contours -> contourLevels, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

It was still very bad, and then I changed my strategy

```
ListDensityPlot3D[potentialData, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Looks much better, and much worse than gaussview produced

[image]

What can I do to match his performance, or even surpass his?

Comment: In the last figure you clearly see 2 contours. Why don't you do the same. You should also plot 2 contours not a huge number of them.

Comment: I don't know which contour line to use at the moment@yarchik

Comment: Just experiment. I am sure that gaussview does not produce the above figure with default settings. And, by the way, this is not a Mathematica question.

Comment: But I'm using Gaussian by default@yarchik

Comment: You use Gaussian for performing the calculations and gaussview for plotting. In gaussview one can change the contour values. And in MA you should do the same, just use `Contours->{-0.1, 0.1}` in `ListContourPlot3D`.

Comment: You can use yours. How do you know it's -1.0 and 1.3

Comment: There is no way to know. You simply select values that make the figure look good and informative. From my perspective it is better to plot a single contour with the value 0.0.

Comment: So the question boils down to "How does gaussview choose contours by default?" I won't vote to close, but I'd say the question is arguably not quite related to _Mathematica_. Perhaps you'll have more luck by asking this in a gaussian related site, or even by reading the document of gaussian? (I'm not a user of gaussian, is it well-documented? )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first issue you are having is this:

```
In[262]:= ToExpression["1.06897E-03"]

Out[262]= -0.0942383
```

It's unfortunate, but that string is interpreted as a number times the constant `E` minus another number. I made the following adjustment to your code:

```
data = Flatten[ImportString[StringRiffle[dataLines, "\n"], "Table"]];
potentialData = Transpose[ArrayReshape[data, gridSize], 1 <-> 3]
```

and it plots nicely.  I remembered the `Transpose` trick from the last time I [wrote code like this](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/131302).

In recent Mathematica versions you can get the plot directly through [Import](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Cube.html):

```
Import["/Users/jasonb/Downloads/C3H4O2-Potential.cube", "Graphics3D"]
```

[image]

Comment: Using the default does work, but it's different from GaussView itself

Comment: My manual purpose was to do the following molecular isosurface electrostatic potential diagram, mathematica does not have this function by default

Comment: You can also use `Import` to get the underlying data and plot it using any custom styling - see [this example](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Cube.html#441551641).  Choosing the right values for the isosurfaces can be a trial-and-error process

Comment: I've seen this, and it doesn't seem to have what I need

Comment: you can look this picture http://sobereva.com/images/443/bar.jpg

Comment: So you have an isosurface and another function that you want to use to color it by?

Comment: Since gaussian can produce a protential cube file and eps cube file, the two should work together @Jason B.

Comment: It is certainly possible to make a plot like you describe - make an isosurface based on the electron density and colored by according to the wave function, so long as they are both defined on the same spatial grid. I've done this before in Mathematica, but it's been a while.