# Plotting the molecular isosurface electrostatic potential map

Tags: plotting, visualization, chemistry

After performing Gaussian calculation, cube files can be obtained.  The distributions are the potential cube and esp cube, both of which contain volume data.  What I want to do now is to project the potential cube onto the esp cube file, which is the "molecular isosurface electrostatic potential map".

"molecular isosurface electrostatic potential map" like this:

[image]

This image was created using the VESTA crystallography software. Although it is quite good, it cannot meet some of my specific requirements.

Below is a part of the code I am working on, with comments.

```mathematica
(* === 1. Define file path === *)
path1 = "http://pic.wxyh.top/C3H4O2-esp.cube";
path2 = "http://pic.wxyh.top/C3H4O2-Potential.cube";

(* === 2. Import volumetric data === *)
espCube = Import[path1, "VolumetricData"]; (* Import esp.cube file *)
potentialCube = Import[path2, "VolumetricData"]; (* Import Potential.cube file *)

(* === 3. Get data information === *)
espData = espCube["Data"]; (* Extract data from esp.cube file *)
potentialData = potentialCube["Data"]; (* Extract data from Potential.cube file *)
dataRange = espCube["DataRange"]; (* Get data range *)

(* === 4. Process data === *)
espDataNormal = Normal[espData]; (* Normalize espData *)
potentialDataNormal = Normal[potentialData]; (* Normalize potentialData *)

(* One of the processing steps for isosurface electrostatic potential maps that calculates the electrostatic interaction energy for each ion *)
projectedData = MapThread[Times, {espDataNormal, potentialDataNormal}, 3]

projectedDataNormal = Normal[projectedData]
```

[image]

The data obtained in the end is of this type. I know that `ListContourPlot3D` can be used to plot the graph later, but I don't know how to process this data. I'm not sure how to convert it into a three-dimensional coordinate format. The data is too long and I'm feeling a bit overwhelmed.

Comment: Stongly related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/105642/1871

Comment: Now the problem is dealing with the data, I don't know how to deal with it, too long data@xzczd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment above, the problem is strongly related to

[How can I convert a 3D contour plot into a region for use as a custom slice in ListSliceDensityPlot3D?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/105642/1871)

And you don't need any advanced technique to obtain the desired plot:

```
mole = Import[path1, "Molecule"];

moleplot = MoleculePlot3D@mole
(* Definition of espData, etc. are the same as yours. *)
surface = ListContourPlot3D[espData[[1]], Contours -> 0.03 {-1, 1}, 
   DataRange -> dataRange] // DiscretizeGraphics

potentialPlot = 
 ListSliceDensityPlot3D[potentialData[[1]], surface, DataRange -> dataRange, 
  ColorFunction -> ({Opacity[0.8], Blend["M10DefaultDensityGradient", #1]} &)]

Show[moleplot, potentialPlot]
```

[image]

Oh, perhaps the `M10DefaultDensityGradient` should be regarded as *advanced*, which is discussed in e.g.

[What's the default colormap (or color scheme) used in mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/162883/1871)

But it's not necessary.

---

It's possible to achieve the goal with `ListContourPlot3D` only, but this solution is a bit advanced:

```
potefunc = 
  ListInterpolation[Normal@Transpose[potentialData[[1]], {3, 2, 1}], dataRange];

help[opt___] := 
 ListContourPlot3D[espData[[1]], Contours -> 0.03 {-1, 1}, DataRange -> dataRange, 
  opt]

range = 
 potefunc @@@ 
   First@Cases[help[], GraphicsComplex[p : {{_, _, _} ..}, __] :> p, Infinity] // 
  MinMax
(* {-0.0615143, 0.366115} *)

moleplot~Show~
 help[ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y, z, f}, {Opacity[0.8], 
     Blend["M10DefaultDensityGradient", Rescale[potefunc[x, y, z], range]]}], 
  Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All]
```

The advantage of this solution is, the obtained surface is smoother:

[image]

Comment: The second part is a little hard to follow

Comment: @我心永恒 Notice a easier way to rearrange the data with `Transpose` has been mentioned in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/283986/1871) under your previous question. If you still feel it difficult to understand, feel free to ask in the comment. (But please be specific when asking. )

Comment: Let me delve into it first