Opacity of ListSliceDensityPlot3D cannot be modified in version 14.0
Bug introduced in 14.0, fixed in 14.1.

The code below cannot change the transparency of the object, what should I do?
data = Table[x + y + z, {z, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {x, -1, 1}];

ListSliceDensityPlot3D[data, Cylinder[], 
 ColorFunction -> ({Opacity@0.1,      Blend["M10DefaultDensityGradient", #1]} &), 
 DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]

After my testing, neither mac, linux, nor windows can work.



…(-1) This is already answered here, isn't it?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/284163/1871

It doesn't work, I've already tried it

It works well, I've already tried it: https://i.sstatic.net/bZTlAvrU.png

my mac ,linux,windows all can not work,version14

Please make a bit more effort in asking a clear question.

you are right，I have change my question

Only 13.3,14.1 work for ColorFunction -> ({Opacity@0.1,      Blend["M10DefaultDensityGradient", #1]} &)

@cvgmt What about other versions?

Still, you forgot to revise the code text.

Can't access v14.0 so cannot test, anyway, does ListSliceDensityPlot3D[data, Cylinder[],    DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}] /.   a_RGBColor :> Directive[Opacity[0.1], a] work?

@xzczd BINGGO! WORKS GOOD

As a member for 6 years already asking 54 questions, you should do a better job in asking question. Perhaps you're having difficulty in reality, but it's not a reason for asking careless question in this site. I'll keep my downvote there, take it as charge for trouble.
Then, turn the comment to an answer. In version 14.0, the bug can be circumvented by
ListSliceDensityPlot3D[data, Cylinder[],    
  DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}] /. 
    a_RGBColor :> Directive[Opacity[0.1], a]


Thank you for your reminder, I was indeed a bit hasty this time, I will pay attention next time
